# Sqlalchemy reflection get_table_names() missing a table name

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I've two tables in my database, `factsales_tbl` and `factsales`. They're both listed if I query the db like this,

> SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_schema =
> my_schema

But for some reason, `factsales` is not being returned by `sqlalchemy.reflection.Inspector.from_engine(conn).get_table_names(schema=myschema)`

`engine.table_names()` also only returns `factsales_tbl` and not `factsales` but `engine.has_table('factsales')` returns `True`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `factsales` a table or a view?

Comment: It was a view, as it turns out. Thank you.